# How to use a value in a list as a reference to another value in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm begging with python so I would like to know how to do a program that reads a code, a price and the quantity of a number of products.
Then the program should print the codes of the more costly product and the code of the product with less units.
Here what I tried to do:

```
Price=[]
code=[]
quantity=[]
Num=x
for i in range(x):
    code.append(input("product code: "))
     price.append(float(input("price: ")))
        quantity.append(int(input("quantity: ")))
print(code[max(price)])
print(code[min(quantity)])
```

ThAnks already!

Comment: What is it doing wrong?

Comment: you need to use `argmax` and not `max`. `argmax` is not builtin in python but you can get it from many libraries like numpy. However since you are learning, I would recommend implementing it yourself, it's a good exercise and not hard.

Comment: you should rename your question to be useful

Answer (score 1):

A few items that are likely causing you trouble:

- `Price = []` should be `price = []`
- `Num=x` should be `x=10` or some other number
- All three lines under `for` need to have the same indent.

To get the code with max price and code with min quantity you want to find the index of the max and min and use that on the code list:

```
print(code[price.index(max(price))])                                                                                                                                                                        
print(code[quantity.index(min(quantity))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to combine all items and `max` for finding the maximum item value.

```
all_items = zip(price, code, quantity)

item_with_max_price = max(all_items, key=lambda x: x[0])
item_with_max_quantity = max(all_items, key=lambda x: x[2])
```